# CoreData model file opens as XML file

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

After resolving some conflict after a merge, when I choose the Data Model file in xcode, it shows me the file as XML and not with the regular interface:

[image]

[image]

The project does compile and run.

**EDIT**: If I copy the file and open it from desktop using xcode, it opens with the interface as suppose to.

Answer (score 0):

After many failed attempts I've deleted the entire project and cloned it again from git.